# Where to submit bug report regarding Google Play Games API?

Tags: android, google-play-games

Does someone know where to submit a bug report regarding Google Play Games API?

I can't find anything on the subject, and there's an annoying bug with the `loadLeaderboardMetadata()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a platform to submit bug report, see here: https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/

Thanks to cavpolo who gave the answer in this thread: [Google Play Services Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696662/google-play-services-leak/21697186#21697186)

Answer (score 1):

I've found where to submit bugs related google play games: https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/list