# Google Play Services Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, google-play-services, google-play-games

I started using Google Play Game Services a while ago, and yesterday while checking the logcat I couldnt help to notice this error:

> E/DataBuffer(3183): Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object
>   detected!  Be sure to explicitly call close() on all DataBuffer
>   extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object:
>   com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@40555410)

It occurs several times in a row. Im not exactly sure why it arises. It doesnt make my app crash nor makes the google achievement/leaderboards functionality stop working.

All I know is that it is related to the functions "unlockAchievementImmediate" and "submitScoreImmediate".

Has anybody encountered this problem before or has any suggestions?

---

**Edit:** In my app I only use "unlockAchievementImmediate" and "submitScoreImmediate". These functions don't return any buffers that need any closing.

Comment: This is also occurring when I use the onStateLoadedListener of the AppStateClient (which has been fun, since no Buffer object is even returned, so not sure how Google expects me to close it!)

Answer (score 7):

These items extend DataBuffer: AchievementBuffer, AppStateBuffer, FilteredDataBuffer, GameBuffer, InvitationBuffer, LeaderboardBuffer, LeaderboardScoreBuffer, MetadataBuffer, MomentBuffer, ParticipantBuffer, PersonBuffer, PlayerBuffer, TurnBasedMatchBuffer.

These are generally found in your listeners of those particular items. For example:

```
public void onTurnBasedMatchesLoaded(int statusCode, LoadMatchesResponse response) 
{
    TurnBasedMatchBuffer buff = response.getMyTurnMatches();
    // do some stuff with buff
    buff.close()
}

public void onPlayersLoaded(int statusCode, PlayerBuffer buff) 
{
    Player p = buff.get(0);
    buff.close();
}
```

The error doesn't report until after I exit my app and re-enter. If I call up my matches 3 times and exit the app without calling buff.close(), I can expect to see the warning 3 times upon opening it back up again. Add in the buff.close() and they disappear. Voila!

Comment: While the above is still correct, I do still find that I have a rogue one somewhere which I cannot account for with any unclosed Buffers... It seems that simply signing in, exiting, and reopening is enough to cause this one. Perhaps the jars we're implementing are causing it.

Comment: It may be the case for Multiplayer/TurnBasedMatches functions, but in my app I only use "unlockAchievementImmediate" and "submitScoreImmediate", which dont return any buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Any SubClass of Data Buffer needs to be released. So after you are done with that object release it.

Data Buffer object contains a `release()` method so after you are done with that object just release it using `databuffer.release();`.

Comment: At the time I was developing the app (I dont know if anything has changed since then), I only used the methods "unlockAchievementImmediate" and "submitScoreImmediate". These functions didn't return any buffers so there wasn't anything that could be released.