# Do you need to "release()" the results of a "queryChildren()"?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-android-api

I had some code that queries for the children of a google drive folder:

```
driveResourceClient.queryChildren(parentFolder, folderQuery)
    .addOnSuccessListener { folderResult -> ... }
```

I was getting errors in my Logcat similar to this (during garbage collection):

> E/DataBuffer﹕ Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!
>   Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending
>   objects when you are done with them.

They seemed to go away when I called:

```
folderResult.release()
```

So perhaps I fixed it (not certain), but it puzzles me that the google examples of querying do not do this.

[https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries](http://google%20drive%20getting%20started)

Does anyone know if this is, in fact, a required operation?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using the Data Buffer the subclass under it needs to be released. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696662/google-play-services-leak). You will also noticed one example [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#data-processing). See the `codec` used data buffer so at the end it was released like in the example `codec.release`.